# Determine when Akka Cluster PubSub will broadcast to peer nodes

Tags: scala, akka, service-discovery, akka-cluster

I'm trying to use the `DistributedPubSubExtension` to broadcast certain actor's existence/location to an akka cluster, but haven't found a reliable way to determine when those messages will actually be broadcast to the cluster.

I initially used `SubscribeAck` as a signal that the channel was ready, but that message arrives without any regard of the node's status in the cluster.

Next I used `MemberUp` and `CurrentClusterState` as a signal, but the messages still did not reach subscribers on other nodes.

I still use `MemberUp` and `CurrentClusterState` as a signal to set up a `system.scheduler.scheduleOnce` to `Publish` my actors existence to the channel and that is finally being received by subscribers on other nodes. However, arbitrary *sleeps* seem like a sure-fire way to fail in the future, when the timing happens to be off.

Is there a better indicator when I might actually reach other nodes with a `Publish` or do i need to roll my own discovery, such as manually calling a *discovery* actor at a known good path on each node as it comes up?